# How to automatically add new terminator instances to a currently open terminator window?

Tags: linux, terminal, terminator

I am currently using terminator for all my terminal needs. However when I open terminator at a new location by right clicking it opens a new terminator window, I would instead like it to be added to the current window by automatically splitting the currently opened terminator window horizontally or vertically. Is this feature available in terminator ? If not can you'll suggest a terminal application which has this functionality.

Comment: You can open a horizontal split using `Ctrl+O` and a vertical split using `Ctrl+E`

Comment: @hek2mgl I want the current terminator window to split automatically as I open terminator in newer locations using the explorer.

Comment: You can make terminator opening a new tab in an existing window using the `--new-tab` commandling option. But why using the explorer? use the shortcuts! :)

Comment: Btw, you need to enable "DBUS Server" in the settings to make the `--new-tab` option work.